# pyparsing to extract the content of a given header

Tags: python, text-mining, pyparsing

I am trying to extract the content of a given text that starts with a specific header.

```
Header Text_A
blablabla
blablablabla

Header Text_B
blablablablablan
blablaa
```

To this end, I have used thepyparsing api in that way:

```
ParserElement.defaultWhitespaceChars=(" \t")
NL = LineEnd().suppress()
END = StringEnd()
header_1=Literal('Header Text_A')
header_2=Literal('Header Text_B')
any_header = (header_1 | header_2)
# text isn't just anything! don't accept header line, and stop at the end of
the input string
text=Group(~any_header + ~END + restOfLine)
overall_structure = ZeroOrMore(Group(any_header +
Group(ZeroOrMore(text))))
overall_structure.ignore(NL)
```

The code works well when I have only an entry text with the above header. However, when I have an entry with the above examples of headers and also another text it doesn't work. 
 For example if I have an entry like:

```
blablablablabla
Header Text_A
blablabla
blablablabla

Header Text_B
blablablablablan
blablaa
```

It doesn't work... However, if I have only the text:

```
Header Text_A
blablabla
blablablabla

Header Text_B
blablablablablan
blablaa
```

it works well..

Have you any idea how can I solve the problems please.

Comment: You need to extract the header part alone or the data part if specific header is present ? Also please explain your question with little more clear examples. I could not even understand the difference between success example and failure example

Comment: I need to extract the data part related to a given header. In other terms, if I found a given header, my function should extract the data present after that header... The code that I have implemented extracts this information although it works only when I have a text that contains only the headers that I have defined. Meaning that works, only if I have a text with a structure containing the headers defined above.  If I have a text which is preceded by a text that doesn't match with the headers, the code that I have implemented doesn't work. Hope that I was more clear, sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Use regex to find whether particular text is present in the header line or not. If found then extract the data part else leave it.

Comment: Have posted my answer. Please check whether it helps

Comment: You've already defined a `text` expression that matches non-headers, why not start your overall_structure with `Optional(text)` : `overall_structure = Optional(text) + ZeroOrMore(Group(any_header +
Group(ZeroOrMore(text))))`

Answer (score 0):

Use regex to check whether particular text (in this case it is "Header") is present or not. If it is present the extract the data part else do not extract.

For example :

```
text = 'gfgfdAAA1234ZZZuHeadijjk'
text = 'gfgfdHeadAAA1234ZZZuijjk'
text = 'gfgfdAAAHead1234ZZZuijjk'

m = re.search('Head', text)
if m:
    extract the data part
else:
    do not extract the data part
```

For all the above 3 text values i.e irrespective of the position the word "Head" is, this code will check whether the word "Head" is present in the text or not and process accordingly

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, I understand the idea. But how should I do it using pyparsing and also how to deal when I have multilnes on data part ?